# Flip iOS app to RTL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I did an `iOS` app using `constraints` and would like to add `localization` for `arabic` plus `RTL` support. By pressing a button it should flip, now most of the results I got was either flipping programmatically or changing the language from outside of the app.

I'm using `Objective-C`.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 you can do something like this :

```
@IBAction func switchTheLanguage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var transition: UIViewAnimationOptions = .transitionFlipFromLeft

    if OHLanguage.currentAppleLanguage() == "en" {
        OHLanguage.setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: "ar")
       UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    } else {
        OHLanguage.setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: "en")
        transition = .transitionFlipFromRight
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }

    let rootviewcontroller: UIWindow = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!

    rootviewcontroller.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "rootnav")

    let mainwindow = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!)!

    mainwindow.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.6477, saturation: 0.6314, brightness: 0.6077, alpha: 0.8)
    UIView.transition(with: mainwindow, duration: 0.55001, options: transition, animations: { () -> Void in
    }) { (finished) -> Void in

    }
}
```

OHLanguage is a class which handles setting app language and getting current app language from Userdefaults.

Comment: Question is for `Objective-C` only.

Comment: @OmarNShamali The question was only about flipping the iOS app to show the Arabic language that is the reason I haven't added any OHLanguage class code.

Comment: then you should have just set the related code, otherwise late night developers will get lost looking for the treasure OHLanguage, lol

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do it using Objective-C:
You can force your UIView to set SemanticContentAttribute as UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft.

For example:

```
if ([LanguageManager isCurrentLanguageRTL]) {
        if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
            [[UITableView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        }
    }else {
        if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
            [[UITableView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
        }
    }
```

Then reload the Storyboard using:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    delegate.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Also you can check this https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_language_manager